# Why is PHP typecasting different from another functions?

Tags: php, casting

Functions in PHP are constructed like this `foo($bar)` with the variable `$bar` as parameter. When you want to convert the values of the `$bar` to a boolean or string, you need to do the following:

```
(string)$bar;
```

I find it that little bit odd, given the syntax of another functions. Why is Type Casting in PHP performed this way, compared to many other languages, like this:

```
ToString($bar);
```

for example. I am seeking to better understand the syntactic design of the language.

Comment: You would really need to visit with PHP's dev team to get the inside scoop on this, beginning with the fact that PHP is loosely typed.

Comment: If you really want to use functions, then there are functions for casting values to [float](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php) and [integer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) and [Boolean](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.boolval.php) and [string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strval.php).... or the more generic [settype()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.settype.php) function.

Comment: Because PHP orientates towards C++.

Answer (score 1):

`(string)` is the actual data type internally. So consider this

```
$bar = 0; //int
$foo = '0'; //string
```

All the `string` conversion does is try to make a single string out of the value. In other words, it simply converts numbers into their character counterparts. It doesn't natively work with constructs, like `array`

```
$bar = [0];
echo (string)$bar; // E_NOTICE: array to string conversion, outputs 'Array'
```

Now, along the lines of your question, objects can have a magic method [__toString()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring)

```
class Foo {
    protected $bar = 'Hi';

    public function __toString() {
        return $this->bar;
    }
}
$x = new Foo();
echo (string)$x; // outputs 'Hi'
```

When we try to convert the `Foo` object to a string it calls the magic method